# Chart X-axis make bigger space between values

Tags: c#, charts

I have a problem with charts in c#.

[image]

Is there some chance to change the lines? On x axis I want to make it like that space between 30 and 100 will be smaller than 100 and 1000.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Comment: What chart are you using?

Comment: Post code of how you set up the chart (i.e., the stuff before you add points).

Comment: i´m just drawing there some points. I have other program where i need to use it and this is just "learning" program.             this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10,10);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(20,10);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(30,50);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(100,100); and i´m using spline chart

Comment: i didn´t set it up...

Comment: Yes and no. The Axis by default will display the data in scale.Your chart however doesn't seem to do that anyway. The reason must be either CustomLabels (unlikely, as using them takes some level of knowledge) or that you add the x-values as__ strings__. Which is usually a bad idea. The x-values are lost, only surviving in the labels and all points are lined up one by one.. Instead of writing maybe AddXY("100", 100), you should write AddXY(100, 100) etc.. Then the distances would be in scale.